# I know the ip of my router. My laptop is one of the devices connected to the router. What is my static ip?

Tags: ip, router, gateway, http-status-code-504

I know the IP of my router. It is xx.xx.xxx.xxx 
My laptop is one of the devices connected to the router. 
My laptop gets a dynamic IP! Currently my IP is 192.168.0.7 and the IP gateway of my router is 192.168.0.1
How can I connect to my laptop from an external device?

http://192.168.0.7:80/xampp/server.php?data=25

This will only be executed if i am connected to the local network.
I will get a 504 gateway timeout error when I connect to this from an external network. How can i overcome this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up port forwarding on your router of lets say port 1200.  Forward port 1200 to the IP of your laptop (192.168.0.7)

Then on the external device to connect to your computer you would map it to address of your router + port forwarded to your laptop:

192.168.0.1:1200

And that should do it.

Edit**
If your external device is on your internal network.  If its not on your internal network and you are trying to access from outside through the internet. Then you need to get your external IP.. if your external ip is 69.69.69.69 then your external device would have to map to:
69.69.69.69:1200
to connect to your laptop

hth

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I needed! I couldn't forward the port to 1200 so I changed it to port 80 and it worked fine! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

`192.168.*` is an [Internal Address block](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_address_spaces), which is why you're unable to access it from outside the network.

You can use sites like [WhatIsMyIP](http://www.whatismyip.com) or [WhatIsMyIPAddress](http://whatismyipaddress.com/) to view your External Address.

Note that you'll need to [open/forward](http://portforward.com/) `Port 80` in your Router and/or Firewall.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use your router's port-forwarding feature as a proxy. Forward port 80 on your router to port 80 on your laptop; then external clients could talk to your laptop.

Answer (score 0):

try running `ipconfig` on your conputer, it will tell you the external IP of the router.

That IP can be dynamic (as in it might change), so u might wanto get a static DNS name for your computer/router.

Answer (score 0):

[Dynamic DNS](http://www.dyndns.com/services/dns/dyndns/) will give you what you want.  It's a program you install on your laptop that sends it's IP to the site when it changes.

Comment: thanks! I forwarded the port 80 to my laptop!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up port forwarding (on port 80) on your router to forward from its external IP to your laptop's internal IP (192.168.0.7).  Then, when you connect from an external network you need to use your router's external IP.  This can be obtained (when you're on the internal network) from [whatismyip.com](http://www.whatismyip.com/), or you can set up a hostname which resolves to the external IP via [dyndns.com](http://www.dyndns.com/) using their agent.

However I'd also recommend setting up either an actual static IP on your laptop or a DHCP reservation so that its internal IP is always the same.